# What's the difference in this while loop?

Tags: javascript

What is difference between

```
while(condition){
    var variable;   
    ...
}
```

and

```
while(condition){(function(){
    var variable;   
    ...
})();}
```

Can somebody explain me defference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the first case the variable is accessible anywhere inside the `while` (and even after it). In the second case it is private and accessible only inside the auto-invoking anonymous function. So the difference is basically in the scope of the variable. The second example seems pretty convoluted without providing more context.

First example:

```
while(condition) {
    var variable;   
    ... // the variable is accessible here
}

// the variable is accessible here
```

Second example:

```
while(condition) {
    (function() {
        var variable;   
        ... // the variable is accessible here
    })();

    // the variable is NOT accessible here
}

// the variable is NOT accessible here
```

Comment: In the first case, the variable is accessible anywhere inside the function containing the while() statement; it doesn't go out of scope at the end of the while.

Comment: @IanClelland, correct, I have realized this and fixed my answer.

Comment: This is actually not exactly true. In fact in the first example variable is even accessible outside of the while condition. For example Java has the kind of local scope that you describe, but in JavaScript the scope of variables is always function-wide. (One might want to see the with statement as an exception)

Comment: What scares me is that this got +5 before anyone complains.

Comment: Sorry for my duplicate comment, I was just too late.

Answer (score 2):

Variables have [function scope](http://robertnyman.com/2008/10/09/explaining-javascript-scope-and-closures/) in JavaScript.  So in the first loop `variable` is visible anywhere inside your function—the function that contains the while loop, that is.

In the second one, `variable` is visible only inside the anonymous function, since that's the function in which it's declared.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, `variable` accessible anywhere in the function that encloses the `while`. That's because JavaScript does not have a local scope, only function scope.

This might be undesirable in some cases and hence the second variant, which encloses the variable (and loop's body) within anonymous function.

Answer (score 1):

The auto calling function basically creates a scope. Variables defined inside it will not be accessible outside the while loop.

```
var i = 0;
while (i++ == 0) {
    var a = "hi  a";
}
console.log(a); //hi  a

var ii = 0;
while (ii++ == 0) {
    (function() {
        var b = "hi b";
    })();
}
console.log(b); //Uncaught ReferenceError: b is not defined
```

http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score -2):

Got closures to consider as well as Darin Dimitrov comments.